# How to set mouse cursor on X11 in a C application

Tags: c, x11, mouse-cursor

I've got a rather large and rather old C application that has been ported to Linux. I'm in charge of getting mouse cursors to work correctly, but having some issues. I was able to convert most of the cursors we require to using the standard cursors provided by [XFontCursor](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/appendix/b/) by using something like:

```
gCursorTable[waitCurs] = XCreateFontCursor(gDisplay, XC_watch);
...
XDefineCursor(gDisplay, WHostWindow(w), gCursorTable[cursor]);
XFlush(gDisplay);
```

This is fine for cursors which have analogs in the extremely limited list of (useful) cursors that XFontCursor provides, but there are other built in themed cursors that I'd like to set. For example, I'd like to be able to set the cursor to bd_double_arrow (which is included in every cursor theme and is the standard diagonal sizing cursor for windows) in my app, but you obviously can't do that with XCreateFontCursor. This seems pretty basic, but for the life of me I can't find any description on how to do it.

I just want to know how other X11 apps are setting cursors, because they are obviously getting them from a global theme and not just using XCreateFontCursor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to use themed cursors is with the Xcursor library.

```
#include <X11/Xcursor/Xcursor.h>
...
Cursor c = XcursorLibraryLoadCursor(dpy, "sb_v_double_arrow");
XDefineCursor (dpy, w, c);
```

The names are standard cursor names from `X11/cursorfont.h`, sans `XC_`. If the theme has extra cursors such as `bd_double_arrow`, these names can also be used (but not all themes have them!)

If a theme does not have a replacement for some core X cursor, the library will fall back to the core cursor.

Comment: I already have the ability to load all the standard cursor names using XCreateFontCursor. While I guess it's nice that I have another way, it doesn't help me much. How are people using displaying a cursor like bd_double_arrow which is in EVERY cursor theme around, but isn't in cursorfont.h.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that you can also use a non-core cursor name like "bd_double_arrow" if your theme has it (mine doesn't!) See the updated answer.

Comment: Well, I tried that on the default kde theme in OpenSuse 12.3 and bd_double_arrow didn't work. They have to have that cursor image, because it's obviously used when you mouse over the corner of a window. Assuming that your solution does work, is there anyway to find the names of those cursors?

Comment: Default KDE themes don't have `bd_double_arrow`. The corner resize arrows are `size_bdiag` and `size_fdiag`. Look at `man Xcursor` to see where cursor images are searched, there's a big list and I don't know where they are in SuSE. I think there's no API to list all available cursor names; to see whether a cursor is provided, just try loading it. Read the source code of Xcursors for deeper insights.

Answer (score 0):

After clicking some links on that page: try [XCreatePixmapCursor](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/pixmap-and-cursor/XCreatePixmapCursor.html).  From its description, it looks like you can create any 2-color cursor you want.

Comment: I don't want to create my own cursor, I want to use the cursors that are set for the theme. Every cursor theme includes it's own bd_double_arrow (which is the diagonal sizing arrow you get in the top-left, and bottom-right corners to size a window) and I want to use that one so my application doesn't stand out like a sore thumb... I just don't know how.