# Change mouse cursor to standard hand cursor in XCB

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib, xcb

Using XCB, I need to change the mouse pointer for a window to the standard hand cursor (whatever that means in Linux, I need a toolkit-independent solution).

Note: loading the "cursor" font and changing the window attribute XCB_CW_CURSOR to XC_hand2 is not a solution. This loads the X11 ugly and unfamiliar hand cursor, not the default Ubuntu hand cursor that you see in Chrome when you hover links.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set mouse cursor on X11 in a C application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857125/how-to-set-mouse-cursor-on-x11-in-a-c-application)

Comment: crud, according to a comment on that question, this isn't standardized. So am I supposed to use heuristics for the name of the hand cursor and try them all until one of them is loaded or what?

Comment: also, say I use the Xcursor library -- is that shipped by default with X or do I have to make it a dependency of my own app?

Comment: libxcursor is normally a separate package. You only need heuristics if your cursor is not in the list of standard X cursors

Comment: @n.m. of course is not on that list, almost no useful cursor is on that list and the ones that are are ugly and not what the user expects.

Comment: So, to change the hand cursor I need to 1) add a binary dependency to my app and 2) try out a bunch of different names until one works (or, throw in the towel and use a 50MB toolkit and add that nightmare to my deployments and my runtime). How can you encourage your kids to pick up programming after this?

Comment: Your rant is misplaced, I am not responsible for your problems with libxcursor. If you are not satisfied with my explanation, try finding a better one. My kids are learning prigramming just fine, thank you. I think they would be able to deduce that "hand2" is the cursor shape you want to use if you want a prettier shape than XC_hand2.

Comment: dude, chill, I didn't even know you actually had any kids. I don't even _know you_. How could you feel responsible for my problems with xcursor? :) Anyway, here's the answer and yes, it's ugly: http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg/2015-July/057494.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you have to:

1. download and build [xcb/util-cursor](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xcb/util-cursor/) because it's not included in older Linuxes
2. use it to load the cursor (they're called "themed cursors")
3. try out a bunch of cursor names because they are not standardized.

Code for loading the "hand" cursor ([ref](http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg/2015-July/057494.html)):

```
xcb_cursor_context_t *ctx;
if (xcb_cursor_context_new(connection, defaultScreen, &ctx) >= 0) {
   xcb_cursor_t cursor = xcb_cursor_load_cursor(ctx, "pointing_hand");
   if (cursor == XCB_CURSOR_NONE) // they come with various names ...
      cursor = xcb_cursor_load_cursor(ctx, "hand2");
   if (cursor == XCB_CURSOR_NONE)
      cursor = xcb_cursor_load_cursor(ctx, "hand");
   if (cursor == XCB_CURSOR_NONE)
      cursor = xcb_cursor_load_cursor(ctx, "hand1");
   if (cursor == XCB_CURSOR_NONE)
      cursor = xcb_cursor_load_cursor(ctx, "pointer");
   if (cursor == XCB_CURSOR_NONE)
      cursor = xcb_cursor_load_cursor(ctx, "e29285e634086352946a0e7090d73106");
   if (cursor == XCB_CURSOR_NONE)
      cursor = xcb_cursor_load_cursor(ctx, "9d800788f1b08800ae810202380a0822");
   if (cursor != XCB_CURSOR_NONE) {
      xcb_change_window_attributes(connection, window, XCB_CW_CURSOR, &cursor);
   }
   xcb_cursor_context_free(ctx);
}
```

Comment: Doing it that way will mean that if the first load attempt is successful, then you'll be executing 5 unnecessary `if` statements. From an optimization perspective, I'd prefer a loop or at least `goto`. See ["xcb change mouse cursor to hand"](http://pastebin.com/jZWBB5Fx) for an example.